# how to draw and animate flowing water in flash

Tags: flash, multimedia

I want to create a flash animation for the working of a small hydro system..I want to add valley, mountains and a river (please check the link below). But I am getting pretty confused about this design thing. So if you can please add a little tutorial about it, it’d be greatly appreciated.

http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=small+hydro+power&um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1350&bih=663&tbm=isch&tbnid=k35RWBNF8iUiRM:&imgrefurl=http://practicalaction.org/micro_hydro_faq&docid=rue9sNcyTY2I6M&w=518&h=358&ei=s7BgTqz5CoTZrQeJ2fEO&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=376&page=3&tbnh=140&tbnw=202&start=34&ndsp=16&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:34&tx=108&ty=70

---

@cwallenpoole: thanks for the links but I am a beginner in flash... and I want to create the animation for my class work. I want to use mouse over properties so that I can see the description/picture on mouse over or download a file attached on a button click. Can you add some more tutorial links related to Pulse Particle System? And please have a look at the link( http://youtu.be/rnPEtwQtmGQ ) below.. the video shows the flow of water towards the turbine and turns it… so can you also help me by adding some links of rotation and how to show the flow of water. Thanks again.

@Benny Geo: I used it and it works great with the pictures but it looks a bit awkward when i use it with a drawing with photoshop or with the colors in flash(its all because i m not a pro..)But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good tut  [thetechlab](http://www.thetechlabs.com/tech-tutorials/flash/create-real-water-effects-with-flash-cs4-actionscript-30/). This will help u to make better effect and better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some tutorials [here](http://www.flashwonderland.com/11-pulse-particle-water-fall/flash-water-fall-effect.html) and [here](http://blog.oaxoa.com/2008/01/21/actionscript-3-fluids-simulation/) which will give you a good start.

Comment: thanks for the links but I am a beginner in flash... and I want to create the animation for my class work. I want to use mouse over properties so that I can see the description/picture on mouse over or download a file attached on a button click. Can you add some more tutorial links related to Pulse Particle System? And please have a look at the link( http://youtu.be/rnPEtwQtmGQ ) below.. the video shows the flow of water towards the turbine and turns it… so can you also help me by adding some links of rotation and how to show the flow of water. Thanks again.

Comment: i just found a website with this flash animation.. but i dn't kno how to add it into my project... please help.... here is the link for the same http://www.electricityforum.com/hydroelectricity.html.. thank you in advance